# Parasitic capacitance of planar pcb coil

Tags: transformer, capacitance

As an experiment I attempted to make a planar PCB coil as shown below:

[image: Coil overview]

Showing parts of a single layer for presenting detail. 
[image: Detailed coil - top layer only]

Together with a an EE ferrite core it generated 85mH of inductance as expected. What was not expected was 11mF of capacitance according to my LCR meter (DE5000 @ 100Hz). Checking 600ohm signal generator and scope also suggests this may be the case, as voltage across the inductor will barely rise even with a 100kHz signal.

Possibly better summarised with an equivalent circuit. Measurement are across terminals differential mode. NOT towards any ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTSaVi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My question is what can be the source of such a high capacitance?

General info:

- Trace width = 100um
- Trace space = 100um
- Producer = aisler (most dense traces allowed by design rules)
- 45 turns, 2 layers, connected in center via
- 1.6mm board - 1.55mm between layers
- 11mF is measured even without the core, so not suppling core data
- The long sides are not directly on top of the other trace layer, specifically to avoid capacitance between layers.
- Total trace length aproximately 15m
- Resistance = 54Ohms. Dont know if this high resistance can confuse my meters? However it doesnt explain why my 2v 600ohm 100kHz signal doesnt get above 200mV. So there have to be quite a bit of capacitance.
- FR4 with 4.4 relative permitivity
- Solder mask with 3.6 relative permitivity.

Replacing LCR meter with Picoscope 2000 Sine generator + scope:
[image: sine gen + scope]

Signal generator and oscilloscope probes are connected in parallel. Signal generator output impedance is rated to 600 ohms. Sweep between 10kHz to 100kHz. +-2V amplitude, which is shown in trace if disconnecting coil. However its always approximately at +-800V with coil connected. I expected the impedance to be enough with 600+ 54ohms to get voltage up to almost +-2V. At least have it vary with frequency.

Something like this:

[image: Circuit simulation]

With 1000pF which is what I would assumed would be a lot of capacitance for a project like this.

No vector analyser available for better details unfortunately.

Testing Cp with LCR heavily depends on frequency:
100Hz: 11mF
120Hz: 7mF
1kHz: 85uF
10kHz: 900nF
100kHz: 9nF

Might all be tool operator errors of course.

Comment: Capacitance from what to what? The two terminals of the coil? If so I suspect it's just a measurement error related to the high resistance, especially at such a low measurement freq.

Comment: You don't mean mF ( =1000uF !) do you? How are you measuring capcitance? By finding the SRF and computing with the inductance? Capaitance to what, the ground plane? Measure the capacitance at several frequencies, does it remain constant?

Comment: you do not have 11mF

Comment: I don’t know about anyone else but the picture appears to have all the turns shorted out in all the corner areas.

Comment: _"11mF of capacitance"_ - wow, you just invented a new type of super cap!

Comment: _"voltage across the inductor will barely rise even with a 100kHz signal."_ - resonant frequency of 85mH || 11mF is 5.2Hz.

Comment: @Andyaka I read: Trace width = 100um, 45 turns … I think the picture appears to be of very low quality :)

Comment: Please provide SI standard prefixes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units - Simply type in k, m, n, p, µ, Ω, …  Are you developing for 100 kHz signals? A VNWA would be a better choice than an estimation with the LCR meter at 100 Hz for a defined spectrum at a higher frequency. Also the ferrit core can negatively influence that 1000 times higher frequency, it's highly frequency dependent.

Comment: @TomKuschel Several of your answers also use K instead of the SI kΩ ... I think there is nothing wrong with writing out ohm and using u for micro: there is no confusion what OP or the commenters mean

Comment: http://g3ngd.freevar.com/pcb.html

Comment: Thanks for the interest. I tried to update my question with more details. I suspect might be using the wrong tools for the job. As mentioned already 11mF is ridiculous